# gwt serialize and de-serialize object from and to a string (client side only)

Tags: gwt, serialization, deserialization

I have java objects used in GWT RPC calls. On the GWT client I need to store these objects in a web sql database. I need to be able to convert these objects to a string and then also de-serialize them from the string. I have seen many aproaches JSON, AutoBean, various other libraries but none seem to be able to handle circular references which I do have in my objects.

Anyone know of a GWT library that can handle my requirements?

GWT RPC itself transmit responses to the client using JSON and handles circular references okay (at least I think so) - So I cannot see why this mechanism cannot be re-used. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If the Web SQL service conforms to JAX-RS or Jackson JSON, use RestyGWT.

There is no conversion necessary on your part. RestyGWT encodes your POJOs to Jackson-compliant JSON.

The flip-side is you would have to read up on JAX-RS, JAXB, Jackson annotations. Which is not a flip-side to me but an exciting opportunity to learn a widely used web service technology.

> GWT RPC itself transmit responses to the client using JSON

- - - that is an inaccurate perception.
- GWT RPC object encoding is deliberately obfuscated and difficult to decipher and format stability is not guaranteed from version to version.
- there is no json in the RPC data interchange.

If your statement were true, then you would not have needed a servlet that extends GWT RemoteServiceServlet to service a RPC request.

BTW, what web SQL service is that? Proprietary in-house?

Comment: I think you have mis-understood me. There are no web services involved. I am talking about web sql database (sqlite db). I need persist objects in the local sqlite database (as a string) and de-serialize the string from the db back into an object. All this is local to the browser.

Comment: restygwt has a jsonencoder/decoder that I could use. It does not support circular references unless I use annotations which I cannot use. I think I maybe forced to try and remove the circular dependencies in my pojos (or making them transient) and use restygwt for json/encoding/decoding or another library like get versatile and add the circular references back at runtime